# When to use "has/have had" in a sentence?

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-constructions

I often see sentences like:

> - I have had this car for 5 years.
> - I have had Ice cream.

I googled it but didn't understood it well.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this car for 5 years.

I have had the ice cream.

Both the sentences are in the present perfect. The word "have" is an auxiliary verb.  The word "had" is the past participle of the verb "have".

The main verb " have" in the form of the past participle has been used in different senses in these sentences.  In the former sentence, it's a stative verb and it implies to own, whereas in the latter it's a dynamic verb and it means to eat.

The present perfect in the first sentence shows the state of your having (owning) this car that started in the past and continues in the present. It's been 5 years since you had (owned) this car.

The present perfect in the second sentence is indicative of recently finished action of having (eating) the ice cream.

Answer (score 1):

These are instances of the present perfect: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html

As you can see in the page linked above, there are many, complex rules governing when to use the present perfect.

Your examples may be particularly confusing because they use the same word "have" in two different ways.  The first "have" in each sentence is the auxiliary "have" required for the present perfect.  The second "have" is "have" used in the sense of ownership (eg, "I have 2 cars").  Its present perfect form is "had."

It might clarify to think of similar sentences using a different main verb: "love".

- I have loved this car for 5 years.
- I have always loved Ice cream.